# zoomable icicle d3 add label in chart

Tags: javascript, d3.js, label, icicle-diagram

I have read the post about to insert a label into a d3 chart but I don't see the text

This is the post: [How to add to text to the Zoomable Icicle d3 graph?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16798487/how-to-add-to-text-to-the-zoomable-icicle-d3-graph)

This is my page with code: http://mirkotinelli.altervista.org/icicle/altro.html

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and also [what have you tried](http://mattgemmell.com/what-have-you-tried/).

Comment: ...and if you find an answer acceptable, remember to click the checkmark <hint hint>

Answer (score 2):

In the following line from your [source](http://mirkotinelli.altervista.org/icicle/altro.html)

```
.text(function(d) { return d.key })
```

you reference `d.key` which doesn't exist in your [json](http://mirkotinelli.altervista.org/icicle/flare.json).

Replace `d.key` with `d.name`

```
.text(function(d) { return d.name })
```